# Unistall opencv 2.4.9 and install 3.0.0

Tags: python, opencv, ubuntu, uninstallation

Im using openCV on Ubuntu 14.04, but some of the functions that I require particularly in cv2 library (cv2.drawMatches, cv2.drawMatchesKnn) does not work in 2.4.9. How do I uninstall 2.4.9 and install 3.0.0 from the their git? I know the procedure for installing 3.0.0 but how do I make sure that 2.4.9 get completely removed from disk?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The procedure depends on whether or not you built OpenCV from source with CMake, or snatched it from a repository.

**From repository**

`sudo apt-get purge libopencv*` will cleanly remove all traces. Substitute `libopencv*` as appropriate in case you were using an unofficial ppa.

**From source**

If you still have the files generated by CMake (the directory from where you executed `sudo make install`), `cd` there and `sudo make uninstall`. Otherwise, you can either rebuild them with the **exact** same configuration and use the above command, or recall your **CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX** (`/usr/local` by default), and remove everything with `opencv` in its name within that directory tree.

Comment: I used the default repository, didn't add any unofficial ppa. I'll try `apt-get purge libopencv*` Is it essential to rum `apt-get autoremove after that.

Comment: No, it isn't essential. You can see what other packages are installed alongside `libopencv-dev` [here](http://packages.ubuntu.com/trusty/libopencv-dev). Since you probably have other packages depending on `libc`, `autoremove` won't remove them. However, keep in mind that when building from source you will need [some dev packages](http://docs.opencv.org/trunk/doc/py_tutorials/py_setup/py_setup_in_fedora/py_setup_in_fedora.html) (disregard the part about Fedora). Keep track as you install these, as they won't get removed automatically later.

Comment: sudo apt-get purge libopencv* would be the most stupid thing to do. OpenCV is related to soo many other things that it would automatically remove everything else... In my case ROS